# Comparing two arrayLists from CSV

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have a general question:

What would be the best way to sort two arraylists based on the values of each other if:

(1) each arrayList contains exactly one column of the imported CSV (via inputStream and bufferReader (for sake of easiness, i will not print this below).

```
//my arrayLists:

List <String> OpenVal = new Arraylist ();
List <String> CloseVal = new Arraylist();


//lists from above contain column 0 and 1 from CSV:
while((reader.readLine()) != null) {

Sting line = "";
String ColTwo [] = line.split(",");
openVal.add(colOne[1]);
closVal.add(colOne[2]);
```

(2) for further clarity, each column of the CSV [colOne [1], colOne [2] contain the following information:

```
//colOne [1]  colOne [2]
   date        value
   friday       32
   tues         21
   wed          5
```

(3) The way i would to sort it would be like this (by value):

```
//colOne [1]  colOne [2]
   date        value
   wed          5
   tues         21
   friday       32
```

(4) I don't find a comparator class to be efficient, as i don't need to write information to the constructor of the arraylist. The list is prefixed by the CSV.

(3) How would be the best way to compare the two lists?

Comment: @CrazySabbath They happen to be in this case.

Comment: How do you want to sort? What are the values? As of now, I would just suggest loop through the size of a list, and compare each of their elements, since you don't provide data, nor the way you want to sort.

Comment: How do you want them to be sorted?

Comment: What do you mean by value? can you give a clear explanation of your desired result?

Comment: @CrazySabbath i want the value digit of the second row to correspond to the date value of the first row so that i can sort the second value and ensure that it is properly linked to the first columns date.

Comment: my bad, it seems I have reading problems, just now noticed your column name is actually `value`.

Comment: @Leemi Does your csv contain only one row for each date?

Comment: Why don't you instead have a List<String[]> where each list element represents a complete row, and its type is an array where element [0] is column 1 and element [1] is column 2? Then sorting would be far easier.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException If i go about creating a list of a 1D array, how would i go about sorting the two columns based on each other?

Comment: @Eritrean As you can see above, each column has [2] rows.  the important thing is being able to sort them based on the values of each other. As if a comparator was comparing the values of a single arrayList that was listed in a new class.

Comment: Do you mean each row has 2 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your csv contains only one row per date you could store your data to map instead of list:

```
Map<String,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    myMap.put(line.split(",")[0], Integer.parseInt(line.split(",")[1]));
}
```

Afterwards you can sort your map:

```
Map<String,Integer> sorted = myMap.entrySet().stream().
                             sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).
                             collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,(e1, e2) -> e1,LinkedHashMap::new));
```

and to print your sorted map:

```
sorted.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or as commented by DodgyCodeException read your lines to `List<String[]>`:

```
List<String[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        myList.add(line.split(","));
}
```

and sort:

```
    Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
            return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1[1]), Integer.parseInt(o2[1]));
        }
    });
```

And finally to print your list just use a for loop, for example:

```
for(String[] row : myList){
    System.out.println(row[0] +" : "+ row[1])
}
```

Comment: how would i print this to console?

would it be System.out.println (sorted); ?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks. Edited my answer using LinkedHashMap to preserve order.

Comment: This will work in most cases - i.e. as long as `Integer.parseInt(o1[1])- Integer.parseInt(o2[1])` doesn't cause arithmetic overflow. That's why there's a method `Integer.compare(int a, int b)`.

Comment: thanks for your answers @DodgyCodeException and @Eritrean! Just to be clear, when you refer to  return Integer.parseInt(o1[1])- Integer.parseInt(o2[1]); does the [1] refer to the column lines in the inital CSV? if this is the case, shouldn't it be [1] - [2] ?

Comment: @Leemi no, the [1] refers to column 2 i.e. the 'value' column. You want to compare the value fields of two lines o1 and o2. Each line is a 2-element array (`String[2]`) whereby [0] is column 1 (the date) and [1] is column 2 (the value). The last line in the answer should be `return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1[1]), Integer.parseInt(o2[1]));`

Comment: @DodgyCodeException thanks! one last question. Using the Comparator method, is the return value print supposed to print directly to the console? or do I have to loop it in order to display?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thank you for your helpful comments. Edited my answer and also added an example how to print the list.

Comment: That's good. Note also that you can, if you want, replace the whole Comparator anonymous subclass with a simple lambda such as `(o1,o2)->Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1[1]), Integer.parseInt(o2[1]))`. What you have is possibly better for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two better routes than parsing into separate column-oriented arrays.

- Write a class containing member fields to hold your values, and implement the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface with its single method [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)). Instantiate and collect your objects into a `List`, then call `Collections.sort`. This approach is best if you have further work to do, or if you have additional business logic to put somewhere.
- Use a library to parse your CSV file, and write a bit of code to sort the resulting tuples.

I will show the second one.

## Apache Commons CSV library

The [Apache Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library has worked well for me in reading and writing [Comma-Separated Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) or [Tab-Delimited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) files. Surprisingly, there are multiple variations of those formats. *Commons CSV* handles at least nine of them.

First, create an example data file. I took the liberty of changing the first column title from `date` to `dow` for `day-of-week` to be more precise.

```csv
dow,value
friday,32
wed,5
tues,21
```

The *Commons CSV* library returns an [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) of [`CSVRecord`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.6/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html) objects. A CSV contains the value of each column in a row of the parsed CSV data. So we can use these objects as a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple).

The `List.sort` static method will do the sorting for us of our collected tuples (`CSVRecord` objects). We need to provide a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) method to make the comparison of each tuple. For each tuple, we extract the second [column by its name](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.6/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html#get-java.lang.String-) defined in the first row of the data file, the name `value` in our data file.

```java
List < CSVRecord > tuples = new ArrayList <>( 3 );
Reader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new FileReader( "/Users/basilbourque/data.csv" );
    CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces( true ).withHeader();
    Iterable < CSVRecord > iterable = csvFormat.parse( reader );
    // Convert `Iterable` to a `List`. 
    for ( CSVRecord record : iterable ) {
        tuples.add( record );
    }
} catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch ( IOException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Comparator < CSVRecord > comparator = new Comparator < CSVRecord >() {
    @Override
    public int compare ( CSVRecord o1 , CSVRecord o2 ) {
        Integer a = Integer.valueOf( o1.get( "value" ) );
        Integer b = Integer.valueOf( o2.get( "value" ) );
        return a.compareTo( b );
    }
};
System.out.println( "tuples before sort: \n" + tuples );
tuples.sort( comparator );
System.out.println( "tuples after sort: \n" + tuples );
```

> tuples before sort:
>
> [CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={dow=0, value=1}, recordNumber=1, values=[friday, 32]], CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={dow=0, value=1}, recordNumber=2, values=[wed, 5]], CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={dow=0, value=1}, recordNumber=3, values=[tues, 21]]]
>
> tuples after sort:
>
> [CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={dow=0, value=1}, recordNumber=2, values=[wed, 5]], CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={dow=0, value=1}, recordNumber=3, values=[tues, 21]], CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping={dow=0, value=1}, recordNumber=1, values=[friday, 32]]]

Finally, loop the now-sorted list of tuples, using `CSVRecord::get` to extract your data for your other purposes.